# Конфликт двух компонентов Swiper на одной странице

Tags: javascript, vue.js, слайдер, swiper

Использую [этот слайдер](https://idangero.us/swiper/).
Добавляю два компонента на страницу.
Первый:

```
<div class="swiper-button-prev" v-on:click="prev"></div>
<swiper ref="mySwip" class="swipper" :options="swiperOption">
<swiper-slide class="swiper-slide swiper-slide_item" 
v-for="(item, index) in pack" :key="index.id">
<div>
{{item}}
</div>
</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
<div class="swiper-button-next" v-on:click="next" ></div>
```

Второй:

```
<div class="swiper-button-prev" v-on:click="prev"></div>
<swiper ref="notMySwip" class="swipper" :options="swiperOption">
<swiper-slide class="swiper-slide swiper-slide_item" 
v-for="(item, index) in pack2" :key="index.id">
<div>
{{item}}
</div>
</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
<div class="swiper-button-next" v-on:click="next" ></div>
```

Первоначально в первом swiper данных больше, в втором к примеру три блока.
Дело в том, что уменьшении ширины экрана, стрелки управления первым слайдером переключают второй слайдер.
Никак не могу понять, где косяк.
Рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

**Vue.js**

```
data:{
    pack1: {1,2,3 .....} //какие-нибудь данные
    pack2: {1,2,3 .....} //какие-нибудь данные
    swiperOption: {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    },
}


------------------------------------------

            computed: {
                swiper() {
                    return this.$refs.mySwip.swiper
                },
                notMySwip() {
                    return this.$refs.notMySwip.swiper
                },
    }

------------------------------------------
        methods: {
            prev() {
                this.$refs.mySwip.swiper.slidePrev(25)
            },
            next() {
                this.$refs.mySwip.swiper.slideNext(25)
            },
}
```

Comment: может косяк в том, что используются одинаковые элементы управления? Замените классы

Comment: @Дмытрык Какие именно классы надо заменить?

Comment: `navigation.nextEl` `navigation.prevEl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая реализация должна работать без конфликта.

```js
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper)
    new Vue({
         el: '#vueapp',
       components: {

         },
         data: {
         swiperOption1: {
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.selectornx1',
              prevEl: '.selectorpr1'
            }
         },
         swiperOption2: {
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.selectornx2',
              prevEl: '.selectorpr2'
            }
         }
         }
        })
```

```css
.relat{
 position:relative
 }
 .swiper-container {
      height: 150px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 38px;
      font-weight: 700;
      background-color: #eee;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include the Swiper library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Swiper JS Vue -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-awesome-swiper@3.1.2/dist/vue-awesome-swiper.js"></script>

    <div id="vueapp">
    
    <div class="relat">
        <swiper :options="swiperOption1">
          <!-- slides -->
          <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
        
          <div class="swiper-button-prev selectorpr1"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next selectornx1"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="relat">
          <swiper :options="swiperOption2">
          <!-- slides -->
          <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 3</swiper-slide>
        </swiper>  
                
          <div class="swiper-button-prev selectorpr2"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next selectornx2"></div>
       </div>
        
    </div>
```